# how post work after post_staus =>'publish' in query post?

Tags: wordpress

I tried the following:

```
$insert = $wpdb->insert( $prefix."posts", array("post_title" => $posTitle,"post_content" => $postContent,"post_status" => "publish","post_type" =>"product"));
```

Using this query I Insert post when I  check my post from admin and click on view is does not work when I update post from backend then it will work but I want to be view post without update it from admin mean afetr insert post with query post should work also use :

```
add_post_meta( $select[0]->productsId, '_wti_like_count', 0, true );
add_post_meta( $select[0]->productsId, '_wti_unlike_count', 0, true );
add_post_meta( $select[0]->productsId, '_wti_total_count', 0, true );
```

without any success. Can someone help solve this problem?

Comment: You should just use wp_insert_post(). It's much easier. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: I Think I need to insert some field in postmeta table for its working

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using an insert for this purpose.

There's a function for exactly what you're trying to do.

`wp_insert_post()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_title'   => $posTitle,
    'post_content' => $postContent,
    'post_type'    => 'product',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
) );
```

The post title variable is misspelled intentionally to match the example provided.